# VBA Excel Macro Oracle XE connection

Tags: oracle, excel, dns, system, vba

I have some Excel Macro VBA codes:

```
Set dbconn = New ADODB.Connection
dbconn.ConnectionString = "DSN=XE_DSN;"
dbconn.Open
```

"XE_DSN" system DNS connection is successful in ODBC Driver Configuration panel.

I have the next error message with macro:

```
[Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified.
```

I can connect to Oracle XE with PL/SQL (I know PL/SQL dont use my system DNS called "XE_DNS") but I cannot connect with macro.

Can you help me why?

Comment: I have found that passing the entire connection string versus the DSN usually works better for connection to Oracle from Excel ADO.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman

I have same error message with this code:

dbconn.Open "PROVIDER=OraOLEDB.Oracle;DATA SOURCE=XE;USER ID=SYSTEM;PASSWORD=mypassword;"


did you think of this?

Comment: I am not sure if it's exactly related, but this is what I did for a recent project: `Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle}; CONNECTSTRING=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=XXXL-DB01)(PORT=nnnn))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=myEnv))); uid=U_I_D; pwd=P_W_D;`

Comment: I exchanged the host, port, userid, pwd, service name. No, its not working with this error message: "ORA-06413: Connection not open". I think the problem is the "Micorosoft ODBC for Oracle" provider.

I think the provider is working fine in my system DNS just it cannot identify the service name. The TNSNAMES.ORA file is looks good. If I exchange some parameter in TNSNAMES.ORA the PLSQL cannot connect to Oracle.

Comment: may the force be with you. Oracle is not fun.

Answer (score 0):

The connection string is wrong.

The correct connection string depends on the driver you use. Typically it can be "ODBC" or "OLE DB Providers"

Looks like you are using ODBC. ODBC driver can be from Microsoft. i.e.  `Microsoft ODBC for Oracle` or from Oracle (like `Oracle in OraClient11g_home1`, depends on your version).

The connection string should be one of these:

```
dbconn.ConnectionString = "Driver={Oracle in OraClient11g_home1};Uid=" & <username> & ";Pwd=" & <password> & ";DBQ=XE_DSN"

dbconn.ConnectionString = "Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};Uid=" & <username> & ";Pwd=" & <password> & ";Server=XE_DSN"
```